# How to find out (runtime) if a type in t-sql is fixed-length or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to find out runtime using t-sql if a type (e.g. nvarchar or int) is fixed-length or not by querying some system-table?

The reason I need to do this is that I need to generate sql-code runtime and need to generate some declarations (`DECLARE @foo SOMETYPE(LENGTH)` or `DECLARE @foo SOMETYPE`) depending on the type of some columns (that are unknown at design-time).

My current bet is that I can check if `sys.all_columns.max_length = sys.types.max_length` and if so assume that it is fixed-length (since `max_length` seems to have a special code (-1), at least for nvarchar).

Comment: What versions of SQL Server do you need to be compatible with?  Some solutions (like information_schema.columns) will only work with SQL 2005 and newer versions.

Comment: SQL 2005 or newer.

I can't seem to find out any good generic algorithm for generating the declaration that can understand both character-types, decimal-types, ints, etc. Just checking the information_schema.columns.numeric_precision/numeric_scale/character_maximum_length doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at information_schema.columns. If a character typed column has a max length it will be specified in character_maximum_length, numeric fields have their precision defined in numeric_precision. A couple notes, to the best of my knowledge the int type is always 4 bytes, also, any of the var types are by definition not fixed length, and only store up to their max length, if a nvarchar(10) holds a 2 character string, it only stores 2 characters. So to detect fixed length strings, you would be looking for the char or nchar types.

Comment: @cmsjr: The storage size of an int is 4 bytes (bigint is 8 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Look at the code for the built-in stored proc sp_columns to see how to do this.